# IndexOutOfBoundsException in a ListView with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, exception, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I've placed a checkbox in a custom array adapter of an listview. The adapter works fine when I check the checkbox. But when I try to uncheck the checkbox in a random manner the application throws.

Here's my code for your reference:

```
holder1.chckbx1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Log.i("checked", "checked");
            positionArray.set(position, true);
            broadCastDetailsLists.add(new BroadCastDetailsList(cpsId2, cpsType2, position, cpsName,handShakeStatus, favouriteStatus));

            sendEnquiry.add(new Q2_SendEnquiryList(searchresultList.get(position).getCpsId(), searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName()));

        } else {
            Log.i("unchecked", "unchecked");
            positionArray.set(position, false);
            broadCastDetailsLists.remove(position);
            sendEnquiry.remove(position);
        }
    }
});
```

Also here's my [log](http://prntscr.com/8nw5no) for your reference

Comment: And what does the stack trace look like? Without that, it's very hard to tell which call is failing. (I wouldn't expect it to be a *string* index out of bounds, given the code you've shown...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue with your logic. When checking a checkbox you'll just add data to lists, while removing an index when unchecking.

Say you check the item at position 1. `broadCastDetailsLists` and `sendEnquiry` now have a size of 1. If you uncheck the same checkbox, you remove position 1, thus the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now I've changed the logic for removing from the lists and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your ArrayList data not found or null , print the list data first and check data .